# Why do I got an exception when I try to get the root node programmatically? System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule.IsUserAllowedToFile

Tags: spnavigationnode

I am using sharepoint 2010. I try to get the rootnode programmatacilly by this code:

```
var rootNode = PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider.RootNode;
```

But I got this exception:

```
  at System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule.IsUserAllowedToFile(HttpContext context, String fileName)
   at System.Web.UI.Util.IsUserAllowedToPath(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.SiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
   at System.Web.SiteMapProvider.get_RootNode()
   at RocNijmegen.Portaal.WebServices.Navigation.GetGlobalNav()
```

Answer (score 0):

that error indicates the current user is not a windows authenticated user!

to get around it use:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

so it would be somthing like:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(getnodes);

private void getnodes()
{
  var rootNode = PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider.RootNode;
}
```

> When generating navigation elements, the
>   NavigationPortalSiteMapProvider class uses the CachedObject interfaces
>   instead of the actual SPWeb objects. The PortalSiteMapProvider object
>   uses SharePoint Foundation cacheable access control lists (ACLs) to
>   check permissions as necessary, and checks permissions only once per
>   family of PortalSiteMapProvider objects.
>        Any SPWeb object that has the HasUniquePerm property set to false is part of a family. If an object's parent has had its ACL permissions
>   checked and the object shares the same rights as the parent, the
>   current object does not need to be checked because the parent has been
>   checked.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalsitemapprovider(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

you cant do the method above within a webservice! it needs to be slightly different! as it runs under the current context of the http serivice passing through would fail! you need to pass through the url to the webservice for it to work! the work has been done for you ;)

```
//method exposed through the web service 
public XmlDocument GetTree(string path) 
{ 
    PortalSiteMapProvider psmp = PortalSiteMapProvider.GlobalNavSiteMapProvider; 
    SiteMapNode node = psmp.FindSiteMapNode(path); 
    return BuildXmlFromNode(node); 
} 

private XmlNode BuildXmlFromNode(SiteMapNode node) 
{ 
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); 
    reutrn BuildXmlFromNode(node, xml); 
} 

//recurses down the sitemapnode children 
private XmlNode BuildXmlFromNode(SiteMapNode node, XmlNode xml) 
{ 
    XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("Node") 
    element.SetAttribute("title", node.Title); 
    element.SetAttribute("url", node.Url); 

    xml.AppendChild(element); 

    foreach(SiteMapNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) 
    { 
        BuildXmlFromNode(childNode, element); 
    } 

    return xml; 
}
```

http://www.techques.com/question/1-518747/PortalSiteMapProvider

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast support. I have try your code and get another exception: An error occured while rendering navigation for requested URL: /_vti_bin/MyCompanyName/Navigation.asmx. Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CacheManager.GetManager(SPSite site, Boolean useContextSite, Boolean allowContextSiteOptimization)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.get_ObjectFactory()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider.GetRootNodeCore()

Comment: is the code within a webservice?

Comment: Yes. This code is inside a webservice.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: I see a method "GetTree". Do I need to give the path of the webapplication where I would like to have the root node? Like "http://intranet.mycompanyname.com". And I see some code where you get all the childs and generate a xml file. I only want the root node as an "SiteMapNode" object. Is this possible?

Comment: Can someone please answer my last question?

Comment: yes you pass the root site collection or webapplication to get the full tree (its children) or subsite to start from the subsite and its children. within the foreach instead of childnodes do NextSibling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode(v=vs.110).aspx